# Does not contain a definition for 'AddToPosts' and no extension method

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am still learning ASP.NET/MVC and following along a tutorial by Matt Blagden (You Tube) on building a Blog..

After making the Post Controller I am getting an error in a snippet of code that handles adding a Tag to a Post if it is a new Post.  My thought is the method AddToPosts should have been generated when I added a new Entity Data Model.

The error is:

> blog.Models.BlogModel does not contain a definition for 'AddToPosts' and no extension method 'AddToPosts'. PostsController.cs accepting a first argument of type 'blog.Models.BlogModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

The portion of code that is giving me the error is:

```
            if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            model.AddToPosts(post);

        }
```

Here is the entire Post Controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using blog.Models;
using System.Data.EntityModel;
using System.Text;

namespace blog.Controllers
{
public class PostsController : Controller
{
    // Access Model
    private BlogModel model = new BlogModel();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // A way to input sample data into database
    [ValidateInput(false)]
    public ActionResult Update(int? id, string title, string body, etc.....)
    {
        //IF not an admin redirect back to index 
        if (!IsAdmin)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        // Get Post
        Post post = GetPost(id);
        // Populate simple properties

        post.Title = title;
        post.Body = body;
        post.DateTime = dateTime;
        post.Tags.Clear();  // first clear tag list

        //ensure input sequence of tag names is not null
        tags = tags ?? string.Empty;

        //Split the sequence into a list of tag names
        string[] tagNames = tags.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, etc...

        //Get or create each tag that was named
        foreach (string tagName in tagNames)
        {
            //Add the tag
            post.Tags.Add(GetTag(tagName));

        }

        if (!id.HasValue)
        {
            model.AddToPosts(post);

        }

        model.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = post.ID });
    }


    // PROMPTS USER TO INPUT DATA FOR DATABASE
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        Post post = GetPost(id);

        //ACCUMULATES LIST OF CURRENT TAGNAMES
        StringBuilder tagList = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Tag tag in post.Tags)
        {
            //Append each tagname
            tagList.AppendFormat("{0} ", tag.Name);
        }
        //Gives the tagList to the view
        ViewBag.Tags = tagList.ToString();

        return View(post);

    }


    private Tag GetTag(string tagName)
    {   // if tag is set then Get the Tag, if not create a new one (Just like GetPost)
        return model.Tags.Where(x => x.Name == tagName).FirstOrDefault() ?? etc....

    }



    private Post GetPost(int? id)
    {
        // IF id is set then Get the Post, if not make a new one..
        return id.HasValue ? model.Posts.Where(x => x.ID == id).First() : etc.....


    // TODO: don't just return true

    public bool IsAdmin
    /* READS SESSION STATE */
    {
        get { return true; /*{ return Session["IsAdmin"] != null && etc...
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Do you have intenseness? What options is it giving?

Comment: Have you tried `model.Posts.Add(post)`?

Comment: Thanks guys... Intelliesense was not giving me any options.. I tried Nico's solution and it appears to work... Now I am receiving a DbEntityValidation Exception... The inner exception is reading null, but I stepped through the debugger and all my entities have data.  Any Suggestions? Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

If "AddToPosts" coming from static class, try adding using statement of namespace where the Add post class exists.